# OutOfMemory Exception in C#

Tags: c#, exception, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am trying to make an encryption software with these codes and whenever I try to encrypt the file it does so well. But whenever I click on the decrypt button. It gives me super high usage of ram whether the created `FileStream` is closed but it still shows me that out of memory Exception was thrown.

```
private void pictureBox7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Audio Types|*.wav;*.mp3;*.3gp;*.m4a;";
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            string OpenedFile = ofd.FileName;
            if (ofd.FileName != "")
            {
                SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                sfd.Filter = "Audio Types|*.wav;*.mp3;*.3gp;*.m4a;";
                sfd.ShowDialog();
                string SavedFile = sfd.FileName;

                string pass = Interaction.InputBox("Enter your desired password to encrypt the audio. Password should contain 8 characters", "Enter Password", "1234ABCD", -1, -1);

                EncryptAudio(OpenedFile, SavedFile, pass);
            }
        }


        //This is the key method to encrypt an audio file
        private void EncryptAudio(string inputFile, string outputFile, string password)
        {
            try
            {

                UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
                byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

                string cryptFile = outputFile;
                FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

                RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                    RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                    CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

                int data;
                while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                    cs.WriteByte((byte)data);


                fsIn.Close();
                cs.Close();
                fsCrypt.Close();

                Properties.Settings.Default.jgu43++;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

                fileSaved fs = new fileSaved();
                fs.LoadFileName(outputFile, password);
                fs.Show();



            }

            catch (Exception m)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error encrypting your audio - " + m.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        //Audio Section Ends
```

Here is the decryption method

```
private void pictureBox7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.Filter = "Audio Types|*.wav;*.mp3;*.3gp;*.m4a;";
                ofd.ShowDialog();
                string OpenedFile = ofd.FileName;
                if (ofd.FileName != "")
                {
                    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                    sfd.Filter = "Audio Types|*.wav;*.mp3;*.3gp;*.m4a;";
                    sfd.ShowDialog();
                    string SavedFile = sfd.FileName;

                    string pass = Interaction.InputBox("Enter the password to decrypt the audio", "Enter Password", "1234ABCD", -1, -1);

                    DecryptAudio(OpenedFile, SavedFile, pass);
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error decrypting your file - Maybe your password was invalid or this file is opened in another program.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void DecryptAudio(string inputFile, string outputFile, string password)
        {



            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key),
                CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

            int data;
            while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);

            fsOut.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();

            Properties.Settings.Default.jgu43++;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();


            fileSaved fs = new fileSaved();
            fs.LoadFileName(outputFile, password);
            fs.Show();

            

        }
```

Comment: Where is decrypt method?

Comment: @viveknuna Hello, I have changed it, please view!

Comment: Don't write a single byte at a time! Use a buffer, or even better; use .CopyTo

Comment: It should be fsOut.ReadByte())

Comment: Thank you! The problem is resolved. Thanks for your help, I have resolved it!